# $f: [a,b] \rightarrow R$ is continuous and $c\in(a,b)$ with $(f(a)-f(c))(f(b)-f(c))\gt 0$ prove f is not injective.

Tags: calculus

$f: [a,b] \rightarrow R$ is continuous and $c\in(a,b)$ with $(f(a)-f(c))(f(b)-f(c))\gt 0$ prove f is not injective.

From the inequality in the question we know that we are mapping to a U shaped graph because either $f(a)-f(c)\gt 0$ and $f(b)-f(c)\gt 0$ or $f(a)-f(c)\lt 0$ and $f(b)-f(c)\lt 0$ and so the function can not be injective.

Is this right?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your idea is correct - and to formalize it, you can invoke the intermediate value theorem. To wit, the first case gives

$$f(a) > f(c) \quad\quad\text{ and } \quad\quad f(b) > f(c)$$

Choosing a number $z$ between $f(c)$ and the smaller of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then the intermediate value theorem guarantees the existence of a solution to $f(x) = z$ on each of the open intervals $(a, c)$ and $(c, b)$.